# Blazor two-way data binding with InputSelect never enters VM property set

Tags: input, combobox, blazor, viewmodel, 2-way-object-databinding

Inside a Blazor component, I'm trying to bind an instance of my viewmodel class to an InputSelect so I can select a value for an enum property.  The VM also has a string property I can bind to a text input.  The VM implements INotifyPropertyChanged, just like it did inside a WPF app, where the enum property was databound to a XAML ComboBox.  A <p> element displays the selected enum property value, as you'd expect from two-way binding.

Whenever I change the string value in the input box, the string property's set gets called, per a breakpoint I've set there.  But a similar breakpoint in the enum property's set never gets hit, even though the <p> it's bound to updates, and I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing.  I know that if I use both @bind-Value and a change handler function, I get an error because then there are two change handlers, but how do I get the first change handler to do my bidding?  Starting to miss WPF's automation mechanisms!

MyVM.cs:

```
namespace BlazorProj.Viewmodels {
  public enum Choice {
    Choice1,
    Choice2,
    Choice3,
    Choice4
  }

  public class ChoiceOption {
    public Choice Key { get; set; }
    public string OptionText { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private string _strValue;
    private Choice? _selectedChoice;

    public string StrValue {
      get { return _strValue; }
      set {
        if (_strValue != value) {
          _strValue = value;
          NotifyListeners();
        }
      }
    }

    public Choice? SelectedChoice {
      get { return _selectedChoice; }
      set {
        if (_selectedChoice != value) {
          _selectedChoice = value;
          DoMoreStuff();
          NotifyListeners();
        }
      }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChoiceOption> ChoiceOptions { get; set; }   // Gets populated elsewhere

    private void DoMoreStuff() {
      // ...Stuff done when new choice selected
    }

    private void NotifyListeners([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

The component, Comp.razor:

```
@using BlazorProj.Viewmodels;

    @if (ViewModel == null) {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    } else {
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="@ViewModel.SelectedChoice">
            @if (ViewModel?.ChoiceOptions != null) {
                @foreach (var opt in ViewModel.ChoiceOptions) {
                    <option value="@opt.Key">@opt.OptionText</option>
                }
            } else {
                <option value="">No options</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
        <p style="color:blue">@ViewModel.SelectedChoice.ToString()</p>
        <input @bind="@ViewModel.StrValue" />
    }

@code {
    MyVM ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

CompPage.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorProj.Viewmodels;
@inject MyVM ViewModel

<Comp />

@code {
}
```

What must I do so DoMoreStuff gets called?  Thanks...

EDIT: I've discovered that the set and DoMoreStuff DO get called if the InputSelect has focus and I hit the up or down arrow key, so I need to make it work for selecting from the drop-down list as well.  Also, removed "Casading..." stuff since it wasn't needed, and corrected CompPage.razor to display a Comp instead of a Tests.

EDIT 2: I've now discovered that DoMoreStuff DOES get called and does stuff on selecting from the drop-down list, even if the breakpoint doesn't get hit.  I guess this is a VS debugging issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Polite] I not sure you're going about this the right way.  There should be no need for Cascading.

I've also removed the `ObservableCollection` which I think you're just using to detect changes in the model.  I use an `EventCallback` instead which is called every time a value is edited and triggers a render in the parent.

Here's my alternative approach to what I think your trying to achieve [I may be wide of the mark!].

The editor:

```cs
<InputSelect class="form-select mb-3"
             TValue="int"
             @bind-Value:get="this.GetChoiceOption"
             @bind-Value:set="this.OnChoiceChanged">

    <option selected disabled value="-1"> -- Select an Option to Edit -- </option>
    
    @foreach (var choice in Choices)
    {
        <option value="@((int)choice.Key)">@choice.OptionText</option>
    }

</InputSelect>

<InputText class="form-control mb-3"
           hidden="@_noDelection"
           @bind-Value:get="GetOptionText"
           @bind-Value:set="this.OnChoiceTextChanged" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<ChoiceOption> Choices { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback ValuesChanged { get; set; }

    private ChoiceOption? _choiceOption;

    private int GetChoiceOption => _choiceOption is null ? -1 : (int)_choiceOption.Key;
    private string GetOptionText => _choiceOption is null || _choiceOption.OptionText is null ? string.Empty : _choiceOption.OptionText;
    private bool _noDelection => _choiceOption is null;

    private Task OnChoiceChanged(int value)
    {
        _choiceOption = Choices.FirstOrDefault(item => (int)item.Key == value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnChoiceTextChanged(string value)
    {
        @if (_choiceOption is not null)
            _choiceOption.OptionText = value;

        await ValuesChanged.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

And the Demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EnumEditor Choices="_choices" ValuesChanged="this.OnValuesChanged" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    @foreach(var choice in _choices)
    {
        <pre>@choice.Key - @choice.OptionText</pre>
    }

</div>
@code{
    private List<ChoiceOption> _choices = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        foreach (Choice choice in Enum.GetValues<Choice>())
        {
            _choices.Add(new() { Key = choice, OptionText = Enum.GetName<Choice>(choice) });
        }
    }

    private Task OnValuesChanged()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have no choice but to implement a change handler in the .razor file?  I must say, I'm not impressed.  The whole point of data binding is to send changes directly to the bound property of the data context class without the need for code-behind to handle anything.  This seems no better than Windows Forms.

I'm not sure about the cascading thing; it's just what I've noticed in the examples I've tried following in the 7 days I've worked with Blazor.

Comment: In general you do just bind against the object properties.  Your example is a rather complex use case.  Enums are somewhat strange objects: they're a thin language wrapper around an integer.  Many people don't use them in their domain objects.  I think of them as cloaked primitive obsession.  And whether you're impressed or not is of no concern to me.

Comment: I just tried making option value point to properties of types string and int, and it still didn't work, so I'm confident the fact that my property was an enum didn't matter.  Remember, the text field directly underneath it mirrored the selection, I just can't get my current code to know when the selected option has changed.  I'm looking for a solution that maintains the elegance of WPF's data-binding, where you didn't need a code-behind change handler function to act on a ComboBox's selection update.

Comment: You were right about not needing cascading.  Please see my edit, thanks.

Comment: And now I'm right about not needing the coded change handler function; see second edit.

Comment: Components are very complex beasts. you need to acquire knowledge before you can start to use them.  In many cases on here the main problem is one of design.   Anyway, question answered.